# MongoDB doesn't respect max for capped collection

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Here's how I'm creating the collection:

```
def connect(self):
    self.client = MongoClient(self.ip, self.port)
    try:
        capped = self.max_size != None
        print("capped", capped)
        print("max", self.max_size)
        self.coll = self.client[self.db_name].create_collection(self.coll_name, capped=capped, max=self.max_size)
    except:
        self.coll = self.client[self.db_name][self.coll_name]
    self.coll.create_index([('expireAt', 1)], expireAfterSeconds=0)
```

I set `self.max_size` to `10`.

Then, I tried this:

```
for i in range(20):
    cache.put(i, {'id': i})
```

I expected to see exactly `10` documents in the collection, but in reality all the `20` documents are in the collection.

Why?

Update: I ran the following in mongo shell:

```
db.getCollection('test').isCapped()
```

And I got

> false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need *both* `size` and `max` parameters to create the capped collection:

```
conn.test.create_collection('test', capped=True, size=10000, max=5)

for i in range(10):
    conn.test.test.insert_one({'_id': i})
```

In the `mongo` shell:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : 5 }
{ "_id" : 6 }
{ "_id" : 7 }
{ "_id" : 8 }
{ "_id" : 9 }

> db.test.isCapped()
true
```

If you try to create it without the `size` parameter, it will output an error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: the 'size' field is required when 'capped' is true
```

However your code have a `try...except` parameter. So it hit this error, then proceeded to the `except` clause, so you didn't see that an error was produced and the capped collection was not created.